# Center a tabular within a tabular within a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, vertical-alignment

This sounds very strange but I needed cell splitting. How can I vertically AND horizontally center the contents in this MWE:

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{MWE}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

&  & Does this really work & this & way? \\ \hline

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}

Testing centering & 
\begin{tabular}{c} This \\ \hline is a \\ \hline test \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} 1 \\ \hline 2 \\ \hline 3 \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} oneoneone \\ \hline twotwotwo \\ \hline threethreethree \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c} 4 \\ \hline 5 \\ \hline 6 \end{tabular} \\ \hline

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

If you look at it you will notice, that 1|2|3 are not centered, as well as the other cell contents. I also tried `\centering` and `\begin{center}` around the cells, without success. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Since your columns are `l`, I'm not sure why you're expecting something different.

Comment: Due to my stupidity I simply ignored the "l" and concentrated on playing with the tabulars ("c"). Anyway, thanks, it solved my "problem" ;)

Comment: Should I delete my question or do you answer my question and I select it as **the** answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding centering of cell content you already got solution in above comments. So, I only suggest to use `\makecell` macro from `\makecell` package instead of nested tables:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{MWE}
    \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
&   &   Does this really work & this & way?     \\
    \midrule
Testing centering &
\makecell{This \\ 
          is a \\ 
          test} 
    &   \makecell{1 \\
                  2 \\ 
                  3} 
        &   \makecell{oneoneone \\
                      twotwotwo  \\ 
                      threethreethree} 
            &   \makecell{4 \\ 
                          5 \\ 
                          6}                        \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also replace your `\hline` construct with rules from `booktabs` package and delete vertical lines. Meany people consider such table design as "professional":